# How to trust a self signed certificate from C# client?

Tags: c#, certificate, self-signed-certificate

I want to establish a connection from a C# client to a server that uses a self signed certificate.
Currently I'm using the 'ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback' to validate the server's certificate.

I tried to install the certificate into the clients Windows certificate store under Personal and Trusted Root Certificate Authorities for the current user as well as the local machine. Unfortunately, neither works.
I can of course validate the certificate by myself in the ValidationCallback and implement some kind of allowlisting, but I was wondering why it isn't enough to install it to the certificate store?

Comment: The correct method should be to install the certificate. But in my experience it can be difficult to figure out the correct store to use. Maybe "Third-Party root certificate authorities"?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just tried to install it to "Third-Party root certificate authorities" but does not work.

Comment: After installing the certificate, are you able to access the endpoint using an ordinary browser?

Comment: No, in the browser there is also a warning message that the connection is not secure. So for some reason the certificate from the store is not used.

Comment: I did some more research and found that my SSL certificate is not signed by any CA. At least the certification path shows only my own certificate. My understanding is that I must install the CA certificate and not the SSL certificate, right? What if there is only the SSL certificate?